# Is it possible to perform a SQL injection attack on this code?

Tags: php, mysql, security, pdo, sql-injection

```
function addUser($username, $first_name, $last_name, $email, $pw, $type) {
include $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/connection_library/connection_library.php';
$insertRow = NULL;
$connection = connectUserLogfiles();
try {
    $sql = "INSERT INTO user_list (username, first_name, last_name, email, password, type) "
            . "VALUES (:username, :first_name, :last_name, :email, :pw, :type)";
    $stmt = $connection->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->bindParam(':username', $username, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->bindParam(':first_name', $first_name, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->bindParam(':last_name', $last_name, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->bindParam(':email', $email, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->bindParam(':pw', $pw, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->bindParam(':type', $type, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $worked = $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->rowCount();
    $stmt->closeCursor();
} catch (Exception $ex) {
    return FALSE;
}
return $worked;
}
```

I have heard that using bindParam will prevent SQL injection attacks. Is this true? Is there a way to execute SQL injection attacks on this code? Assuming I perform no filtering or sanitizing on the parameters (with the exception being the password, which has been encrypted with a strong one way encryption scheme), how would you perform a SQL injection attack?

The database is a MySQL database, and the user being used in the `connectionUserLogfiles()` function only has SELECT, INSERT and UPDATE privileges.

Comment: As long as you use parameterized queries (like you do), have disabled the emulate prepares option (PDO silently falls back to escaping parameters if running on old software), and use UTF-8 (UTF-7 might give you problems), you are good. For a shorter code you could try using unnamed placeholders (?) and just sending in an array of values into the execute function.

Comment: I don't mind the slightly longer code because it makes it easier to understand at-a-glance.

IMO: readability > length

Comment: Yup. Looks perfectly fine to me. Assuming that that `$pw` is a decently salted/hashed password (e.g. using `password_hash()`), there's nothing to ring alarm bells there.

Comment: $pw uses MD5 and SHA-512 with a pseudorandomly generated salt, but I don't use password_hash(), I use crypt().

Comment: Use `password_hash()`. You'll be happier that you did.

Answer (score 0):

> I have heard that using bindParam will prevent SQL injection attacks. Is this true?

[Yes](https://paragonie.com/blog/2015/05/preventing-sql-injection-in-php-applications-easy-and-definitive-guide), provided that you [disable emulated prepares](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12202218/2224584) (they're enabled by default) and your database driver isn't stupid.